# MVC2 Client validation with Annotations in View with RenderAction

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, renderaction

I'm having problem with client side validation on a View that renders a dropdownlist with help of a Html.RenderAction.

I have two controllers. SpecieController and CatchController and I've created ViewModels for my views. 
I want to keep it as DRY as possible and I will most probably need a DropDownList for all Specie elsewhere in the near future.

When I create a Catch i need to set a relationship to one specie, I do this with an id that I get from the DropDownList of Species.

**ViewModels.Catch.Create**

```
[Required]
public int Length { get; set; }

[Required]
public int Weight { get; set; }

[Required]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
public int SpecieId { get; set; }
```

**ViewModels.Specie.DropDownList**

```
public DropDownList(IEnumerable<SelectListItem> species) { this.Species = species; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Species { get; private set; }
```

My View for the Catch.Create action uses the ViewModels.Catch.Create as a model.

But it feels that I'm missing something in the implemetation. What I want in my head is to connect the selected value in the DropDownList that comes from the RenderAction to my SpecieId.

**View.Catch.Create**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BC.ProjectName.Web.ViewModels.CatchModels.Create>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Weight) %>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight) %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Length) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Length) %>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Length) %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpecieId) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%-- Before DRY refactoring, works like I want but not DRY 
                      <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SpecieId, Model.Species) %>
                    --%>
                    <% Html.RenderAction("DropDownList", "Specie"); %>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpecieId) %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" />

        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

**CatchController.Create**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModels.CatchModels.Create myCatch)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Can we make this StronglyTyped?
        int specieId = int.Parse(Request["Species"]);

        // Save to db
        Catch newCatch = new Catch();
        newCatch.Length = myCatch.Length;
        newCatch.Weight = myCatch.Weight;
        newCatch.Specie = SpecieService.GetById(specieId);
        newCatch.User = UserService.GetUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name);

        CatchService.Save(newCatch);

        // After save redirect
        return Redirect("/");
    }

    // Invalid
    return View();
}
```

This scenario works but not as smooth as i want.

1. ClientSide validation does not work for SpecieId (after i refactored), I see why but don't know how I can ix it.
2. Can I "glue" the DropDownList SelectedValue into myCatch so I don't need to get the value from Request["Species"]

Thanks in advance for taking your time on this.

Comment: could you please page the entire code of your view and the create action?

client side validation is often applied with the following html helper: `Html.EnableClientSideValidation()`

Comment: Entire code, pasted. ClientValidation works for the other fields, Length & Weight. And it worked for the dropdown too before I refactored to RenderAction. The Species collection was then placed inside the Catch.Create object next to the Lenght, Weight and SpecieId props.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is any help, but I am using xVal instead of MVC2's client validation, and it works fine under the scenario you have described. I have lots of client side validated DropDownLists and I mostly render them with RenderAction.